# $K(u,v)=K(u)(v)$ true or false

Tags: field-theory

Is it true that if $K$ is a field and $u,v$ are algebraic over $K$ then $K(u,v)=K(u)(v)$ for example $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=Q(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt3))$ if yes can someone provide a proof?

Comment: It just follows from the definitions. If $L/K$ is a field extension and $S\subseteq L$ then $K(S)$ is the smallest subfield of $L$ which contains $K$ and the set $S$. Use this to show a two sided inclusion in your problem, this is very easy. You don't even need $u,v$ to be algebraic.

Comment: Right, it is not hard to prove that $K(u,v)\subseteq K(u)(v)$ and that $K(u)(v)\subseteq K(u,v).$

Comment: Note this is true whether $u,v$ are algebraic or not.

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses: $Q(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3}))$. Also, use `\mathbb{Q}` to produce $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I can show that $K(u)(v) \subset K(u,v)$ using fact that $K(u)(v)=\{a+bv : a,b \in K(u)\}$, but other direction seems harder because I think $K(u,v)$ is not equal to $\{a+bu+cv : a,b,c \in K\}$

Comment: @romperextremeabuser $K(u)(v)$ is almost never equal to $\{a+bv: a,b\in K(u)\}$. I mean, why would this set be closed under multiplication? This is true only when $v$ is algebraic of degree at most $2$ over $K(u)$. I wrote the definition of $K(S)$ in my comment, but seems like you just decided to ignore it.

Comment: I used it combined with things I said but it's wrong so I don't know how to prove this

Comment: @romperextremeabuser Look, $K(u,v)$ contains $K$ and $u$, and so by definition contains the field $K(u)$. It also contains the element $v$, and so contains $K(u)(v)$ by definition. So $K(u)(v)\subseteq K(u,v)$. I'll leave the other inclusion to you, it is very similar. (even easier actually)

Answer (score 0):

$K(X)=\langle K \cup X \rangle $ by definition, i.e. $K(X)$ is the field generated by $K \cup X$.

$K(u,v) \subset K(u)(v)$, proof:

$$K(u,v)=\langle  K \cup \{u,v\}\rangle =\langle K \cup \{u\}\cup \{v\}\rangle\subset\langle \langle K \cup \{u\}\rangle \cup \{v\}\rangle=\langle K(u)\cup \{v\}\rangle=K(u)(v).$$

$K(u)(v) \subset K(u,v)$, proof:

$$K(u)(v)=\langle K(u)\cup \{v\}\rangle=\langle \langle K \cup \{u\}\rangle \cup \{v\}\rangle \subset \langle \langle K \cup \{u\}\cup \{v\}\rangle \cup \{v\}\rangle= \langle K(u,v)\cup \{v\}\rangle =\langle K(u,v)\rangle=K(u,v).$$

Hence, $K(u)(v) = K(u,v).$